# <rich:listShuttle> usage

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam

```
<rich:listShuttle sourceValue="#{positionList.resultlist)}"

      targetValue="#{cvHome.instance.positions}"

       var="pos"
       sourceCaptionLabel="Current Positions"
       targetCaptionLabel="Interested Positions"
       sourceListWidth="300"
       targetListWidth="300"">
     <rich:column>
          <f:facet name="header">Positon Name</f:facet>
          <h:outputText value="#{pos.name}"/>
     </rich:column>
     <s:convertEntity/>
</rich:listShuttle>
```

Error: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /cvGiris.xhtml @526,48 sourceValue="#{positionList.resultList}": Property 'resultList' not writable on type java.util.List

How can i handle with this problem ???

Answer (score 2):

The exception is telling that the setter is missing. Add it to the bean with the name `positionList`:

```
public void setResultList(List<Result> resultList) {
    this.resultList = resultList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But i have a seam entity with the name of Position. "#{positionList.resultlist)}" it returns me a resultlist from the database. "#{cvHome.instance.positions}" it is a Position arraylist. i think this problem stems from this difference :D